# I have two Ids in the same Row where the Id is seperated by Comma and wanted only one Id how to get that Any Leads

Tags: java, selenium

Scenario:

As seen in the above screen there are 2 ids in the same row which are seperated by comma.

My method is there where i get the lastest id.The Problem over here is it fetches both the Ids.
Since i use the id to search i dont want both the Ids.

Below is my method which i use to Fetch the Ids

```
public static HashMap<String, String> Values; 
    
public static void PlanningScreenFetchPlanningandDemandID(WebDriver driver) throws InterruptedException
    {
                    
        Values = new HashMap<String, String>();

        
        
        List<WebElement> tableValue = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span"));

        int tableValueSizes = tableValue.size();

        WebElement latestIds = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//table//tr//td[contains(@class,'mat-column-demandId')]//span)["+tableValueSize +"]"));

        
        
        Values.put("latestDataId", latestIds.getText()); 
        
        
        System.out.println(Values.put("latestDataId", latestIds.getText()));
        
        
        String Id = AppXPathsConstants.columnInputEntryXpath_replace.replace("XXXX", "ID") ;
        inputEntry(driver, Id , Values.put("latestDataId", latestId.getText()));
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `latestIds.getText()` prints this `4306`, `4307` in the console, and your intention is to get only id (I'd assume the first one), then you can try the below code :

```
String firstID = latestIds.getText().split(",")[0];
String secondID = latestIds.getText().split(",")[1];
```

also if there are trailing spaces, make sure to use `.trim` to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are getting Ids here:

```java
latestIds.getText()
```

So you can simply split the Id values as following:

```java
String bothIds = latestIds.getText();  
String [] ids = bothIds.split(",");
```

To give better answer we need to get more details about that web page, not a pictures
**UPD**
You can get each separate id from the array above simply as following:
First id value:

```
ids[0]
```

The second id value:

```
ids[1]
```

Comment: @Prophet-Do you need the HTML or what other information is required pls let me know

Comment: Preferably the link to that page. Also not really clear why do you need to separate these ids, is just splitting resolves your problem?

Comment: @Prophet- Unfortunately iam not supposed to share the link and moreover you would need access rights .Second the split function will remove the comma and will add both the ids without space .My intention is to get only one Id and not both the Ids and any inputs on that will be helpful -@Prophet